# Integrate the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{t\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{t\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{t\sqrt{t}}}{\sqrt{t}}dx$$

$$u = \sqrt{t} \\ du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} $$

$$ 
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{tu}}{\sqrt{t}}dx = 
2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tu} du = 
\frac{2}{t}e^{tu} = \frac{2}{t}e^{t\sqrt{x}}
$$

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}F(x) = \frac{2}{t} e^{t\sqrt{t}} - \frac{2}{t}e^{t\sqrt{1}} = 0$$

I am just wondering if I came to the conclusion correctly abut this improper integral that this function is convergent because it converges towards 0

---

edit: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Does $t$ get treated as an arbitrary constant in the differentiation? 
$$
u = t\sqrt{x} \\
du = \frac{t}{2\sqrt{x}} \\
\frac{2}{t} du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \\
 $$

$$\int \frac{e^{t\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}} 
= \frac{2}{t} \int e^{u} du 
= \frac{2}{t} \frac{1}{u} e^{u} = \frac{2}{t\sqrt{x}}e^{t\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: What is the variable of integration?

Comment: That's where it got confusing. It should be `dx` though, but I think I just foolishly tried to condense down to a single variable `t` without any math reasoning behind it

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the first line?

Comment: Um, there was no reasoning...let me edit for clarity and please see the second edit I added in with different $u$-substitution values. Edit: The first u-substitution is basically done incorrectly and everything is messed up about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line doesn't make sense. You need to notice that the function has a singularity at $x=0$ (it goes to infinity). So, you must consider

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{t\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}\ \text dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^1\frac{e^{t\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}\ \text dx + \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_1^T\frac{e^{t\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}\ \text dx$$
(the $1$ in the integral bounds can be replaced with any positive real number)

Now, we need to evaluate

$$\int \frac{e^{t\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}\ \text dx = \frac{2}{t} \int e^u\ \text du = \frac{2}{t} e^{t\sqrt x} + C$$

(without $\sqrt x$ in the denominator like in your solution)

Using this result, we get

$$I=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left.\frac{2}{t}e^{t\sqrt x}\right|_\epsilon^1 + \lim_{T \to \infty} \left.\frac{2}{t}e^{t\sqrt x}\right|_1^T = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{2}{t}(e^t-e^{t\sqrt\epsilon}) + \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{2}{t}(e^{t\sqrt T}-e^t) = \cdots=-\frac{2}{t}$$

This is valid under the assumption that $t<0$ (because then $e^{t\sqrt T} \to 0$). If $t > 0$ then the second limit is $+\infty$ and the integral diverges. For $t=0$, $\frac{2}{t}$ is undefined so we have to look at
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\ \text dx$$
This integral diverges to $+\infty$.

Therefore, the final solution is

$$I = \begin{cases} -\frac{2}{t}, &\text{for } t<0 \\ +\infty, & \text{for } t\ge 0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $$t\sqrt{x}=u$$ then $$du=\frac{t}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$. It is $$\int e^udu=e^u+C$$

Comment: @DrSonnhardGrauber please see my edit and corresponding question in main post, thank you

Comment: Okay. And the $\frac{2}{t}$ should be outside of the integral and the answer is $\frac{2}{t}e^u$?

Comment: Yes this is right so!